# FFmpeg concat messes up last frame of first segment

Tags: ffmpeg, video, concatenation

**The Problem:**
I routinely need to cleanly concatenate two .MKV files with ffmpeg. About 10-20% of the time, the last 3-5 frames of the first video segment has issues in various video players (VLC and PotPlayer for testing). The typical effect is that while playing the video, the third- to fifth-to-last frame from the first segment being concatenated will freeze and stay on the screen over the next few frames, until the beginning of the second segment being concatenated. The audio still plays properly behind the image. Oddly, if I use the 'e' control in VLC to step frame-by-frame through the sequence, all the frames appear to be there. Both segments are taken from the same source and have all the same properties. The source segment does *not* have this issue on it's own. The source segments are being encoded themselves when being produced, so they shouldn't have any keyframing issues.

**What I've tried:**

- Encoding just the video when issuing the concatenation command (copying audio and subtitles)
- Encoding the video and the audio when issuing the concatenation command (copying subtitles)
- Increasing the values for analyzeduration and probesize as the warnings suggest
- Outputting only the video still produces the issue (no audio, no subtitles)
- I've seen posts about problems very nearly like this, but I can't seem to find the silver bullet

**What I'm doing that produces this issue:**
The command I'm issuing is

```
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i "C:\Users\test\Downloads\ConcatListTEMP00000.txt" -c copy -map 0 "C:\Users\test\Downloads\TEST JOIN COPY.mkv"
```

The contents of the concatenation file are

```
file 'C:\Users\test\Downloads\CutSegmentTEMP0001.mkv'
file 'C:\Users\test\Downloads\CutSegmentTEMP0002.mkv'
```

Here is a pastebin link to the console output when running the above command:
https://pastebin.com/mpBS6TZY

Comment: Upload the log to an external host like pastebin and link it.

Comment: Added the link to the question

Answer (score 0):

Using trim, atrim, and concat filters in a filtergraph appears to have resolved the issue. I will deal with the subtitles separately.